# Spring tool suit could not build with maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, build

my project can be built from the command line with `maven clean install` but i cannot update it through maven-> update project. it says

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4

i have tried installing maven-resources-plugin.jar manually to the repository, still its the same.

Comment: When you do "Maven > Update Project...", check "Force updates of snapshots / releases" and see it that helps.

Comment: i had to configure the maven plugin of STS to use maven 3 and give the path of the repository. that resolved the issue.Thanks